# Which Place to write connection.close() and preparedstatement.close()

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, prepared-statement

I am new in JDBC ...

Student class has methods like Constructor, add(),update() and delete() etc ...

Open a Connection in Constructor. Which Place to write conn.close() and pstmt.close() in below code Help Me

```
class Student
{
    Connection conn;

    PreparedStatement  pstmt;

    ResultSet rs;

    public Student()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","root");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             System.out.println("Error :"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }


    public void add(int rollno,String name)
    {
        try
        {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into student values (?, ?)");

            pstmt.setInt(1,rollno);

            pstmt.setString(2, name);

            int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();

            if (i != 0) {
                System.out.println("Record Inserted");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Record Not Inserted");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             System.out.println("Error :"+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void update(int rollno,String name)
    {
        try
        {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("update student set name=? where rollno=?");

            pstmt.setString(1, name);

            pstmt.setInt(2,rollno);


            int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();

            if (i != 0) {
                System.out.println("Record Updated");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Record Not Updated");
            }


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             System.out.println("Error :"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void delete(int rollno)
    {
        try
        {
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("delete from student where rollno=?");

            pstmt.setInt(1,rollno);


            int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();

            if (i != 0) {
                System.out.println("Record Deleted");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Record Not Deleted");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             System.out.println("Error :"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should add another method to close the connection, and just invoke it on your object when you are done with operations.

```
public void closeConnection() {
    conn.close();
}
```

Also it would be good idea to create another method to open connection, not to open it from constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the sample code that you have posted, it seems all the operations that your trying to do like `Add` `Update` and `Delete` all use the same connection object created globally and initialized in your constructor "Student()". `This is not a standard practice`

As per standards you should not do that, you should create new connections as `local` variables on each of the operations like 'add', 'update' and 'delete' seperately

Also keep in mind if your are using 'Bean managed transaction' then you need to commit the transaction before closing it.Or else add `conn.commit();` in the finally block

Here is a quick example on how a your method should be

```
public void add(int rollno,String name)
{
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    try
    {
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into student values (?, ?)");

        pstmt.setInt(1,rollno);

        pstmt.setString(2, name);

        int i = pstmt.executeUpdate();

        if (i != 0) {
            System.out.println("Record Inserted");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Record Not Inserted");
        }

    } catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error :"+e.getMessage());
    } finally {
         if(pstmt!=null) {
             pstmt.close();
         }
         if(conn!=null) {
             conn.comit(); // Add this line ONLY if you use bean managed transaction
             conn.close();
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you think my answer deserves it, you can mark as Correct Answer

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I wouldn't open the connection in the constructor, since it can lead to many connections being open for a long time without being used, and since connections are a limited resource, you should keep them open for as little time as possible.

I would open and close the connection (and the prepared statements) in each method that uses it (`add`, `update`, `delete`, etc...). This way the connection would only be open when it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a try-catch-finally block and close the connection within the finally.

```
Connection con;
try
{
  con = new Connection(...);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
 //Error Handling
}
finally
{
  connection.close();
}
```

Or you use a try-with-resource and let the VM take care of closing the connections (In this case, you do not need to declare the Connection as field but have one for each action):

```
try(Connection con = new Connection(...))
{

}
catch()
{

}
```

Comment: For information - second `try-with-resource` was introduced in `Java 7`

Answer (score 0):

Add a `finally` block after the `catch` blocks to close the `PreparedStatement` and `Connection` object. Something like

```
catch (Exception d) {
   //do whatever you want when exception occurs
}
finally {
    //close resultset
    //close prepared statement
    //close connection object
}
```

`finally` ensures that the resources are closed before the control returns. Resources will be closed even if you are using `return` inside the `try` block.